# Finding the supremum and infimum of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

For the following subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, give their supremum, maximum, infimum, and minimum, if they exist. Otherwise, indicate that they do not exist.

- $A=\displaystyle\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-\frac{1}{n},1+\frac{1}{n}\right)$
- $B=\displaystyle\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\left[\frac{1}{n},2-\frac{1}{n}\right]$

For the first one, we have $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-\frac{1}{n},1+\frac{1}{n}\right)=(1,1)=\{1\}$. Hence, we have that $\sup A=\max A=\inf A=\min A=1$.

For the second one, we have $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\left[\frac{1}{n},2-\frac{1}{n}\right]=[0,2]$. Hence, we have that $\sup B= \max B=2$ and $\inf B=\min B=0$.

> Apparently, for the second one, I am supposed to have that $\sup B=2$ and $\max B=\mathrm{DNE}$ (does not exist). Also, $\inf B=0$ and $\min B=\mathrm{DNE}$. Where am I going wrong? Did I not compute $B$ correctly or is the textbook off? Since the upper bound for the family of unions in $B$ is $\infty$ and not $n$, a finite number, it seems we should have $B=[0,2]$ and not $B=(0,2)$, as the textbook seems to be indicating. Where am I going amiss? Or am I?

Comment: Note that $0$ and $2$ are not in your union.   For example, $0$ is not in any of the sets that are being unioned.

Comment: $B=(0,2)$, not $[0,2]$

Comment: For the second $B=(0,2)$ since $0$ and $2$ do not belong to the intervals  $[1/n,2-1/n]$.

Comment: Since $2>2-1/n$ for all $n$, therefore $2$ is not in the Union of the given intervals.

Comment: @GregoryGrant As $n\to\infty$, don't I eventually have an interval of the form $[1/n,2-1/n]=[0,2]$ because $n$ tends to infinity and not a finite number?

Comment: @Rudy Notice that $0$ is not in any of your intervals $[\frac1n,2-\frac1n]$ for any $n$, so it cannot be in the union.  Same with $2$.

Comment: @Rudy This is the classic example of how you can union infinitely many closed intervals and end up with an open interval.

Comment: @Rudy Remember, if something is in a union it *has* to be in *at least one* of the sets.  Infinity notwithstanding.

Comment: @Rudy: Just recall that $\frac{1}{n} \to 0$ but $\frac{1}{n} \neq 0$ for all $n \geq 1.$

Comment: @GregoryGrant Thanks for your comments. I think I see the error in my reasoning now.